# Shell/Bash parsing text file

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, awk, text-processing

I have this text file, which looks like this

```
Item:
SubItem01
SubItem02
SubItem03
Item2:
SubItem0201
SubItem0202
Item3:
SubItem0301
...etc...
```

And I need is to get it to look like this:

```
Item=>SubItem01
Item=>SubItem02
Item=>SubItem03
Item2=>SubItem0201
Item2=>SubItem0202
Item3=>SubItem0301
```

I am aware of the fact, that I need two for loops to get this. I did some tests, but... well, it didn't end up well.

```
for(( c=1; c<=lineCount; c++ ))
do

   var=`sed -n "${c}p" TMPFILE`
   echo "$var"

   if [[ "$var" == *:* ]];
   then
   printf "%s->" $var
   else
   printf "%s\n"
   fi
done
```

Could anyone please kick me back on the road? I tried bunch of variete ways, but I am not getting anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: No, you don't need two loops. Is this an assignment? We had someone else with the same problem, also coming in with the misconception that nested loops were the right solution not so long back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to continue down the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) shell road, you can do something like this:

```
item_re="^(Item.*):$"
while read -r; do
    if [[ $REPLY =~ $item_re ]]; then
        item=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    else
        printf "%s=>%s\n" "$item" "$REPLY"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, this is probably exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Text parsing is best done with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/:$/{sub(/:$/,"");h=$0;next}{print h"=>"$0}' file
Item=>SubItem01
Item=>SubItem02
Item=>SubItem03
Item2=>SubItem0201
Item2=>SubItem0202
Item3=>SubItem0301
```

Answer (score 3):

Using awk

```
awk '/:/{s=$1;next}{print s OFS $0}' FS=: OFS="=>" file
```

Comment: Be sure I would do that... if my reputation was high enough.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another `awk` alternative:

```
awk -F: '/^Item/{ITM=$1} !/^Item/{print ITM"=>"$0}'
```

If a line begins with 'Item', save the item name in ITM. If the line *does not* begin with 'Item', print the previously saved item name (ITM), '=>', and the sub item. Splitting on : makes it easier to get the item name.

The assumption is that groups of subitems will always be preceded by an Item: entry, so the variable ITM should always have the name of the current group.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation? Currently your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @bjb568 I've added an explanation. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

[TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) Solution:

```
@(collect)
@left:
@  (collect)
@right
@  (until)
@(skip):
@  (end)
@(end)
@(output)
@  (repeat)
@    (repeat)
@left=>@right
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)

$ txr regroup.txr data.txt
Item=>SubItem01
Item=>SubItem02
Item=>SubItem03
Item2=>SubItem0201
Item2=>SubItem0202
Item3=>SubItem0301
```